# Correct configuration for swashbuckle for IdentityServer4 ClientCredentials on CORE 3.1 visual studio 2019

Tags: swagger, identityserver4, swashbuckle, .net-core-3.1, clientcredential

I have an API I need to make authorized (Using attribute [Authorize])
Identity server 4 configured using generated DB including tables Clients, Scope, ClientScope, Client Secrets.

I have client InternalClient with secret InternalClientSecret which works perfect if authorizing from code.

But I can't figure out how to configurate right swashbuckle for make swagger make authorized requests

[image]

[image]

After pressing authorize button:
[image]

Also API list change appearance:
[image]

If I reach the API I get 401, if I press lock button I see:
[image]

Code behind:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Main API v1.0", Version = "v1.0" });

            if(configuration != null)
            {
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
                    {
                        ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                        {
                            TokenUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:44339/connect/token"),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                            {
                                { "LookupsApi", "LookupsApi" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            }
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });

            }

            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
        });

        return services;
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerDocumentation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "Versioned API v1.0");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Our Awesome API V1");
            c.OAuthClientId("InternalClient");
            c.OAuthClientSecret("InternalClientSecret");
        });

        return app;
    }
internal class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var hasAuthorize = context.ApiDescription.CustomAttributes().OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();

        if (hasAuthorize)
        {
            operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" });
            operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" });

            operation.Security ??= new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>(); //new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();
            var openApiSecurityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement();
            openApiSecurityRequirement.Add(new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2 }, new List<string> {
                    "LookupsApi"
                });
            operation.Security.Add(openApiSecurityRequirement);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, any ideas? Or maybe someone has a working example?